# Firebase curl add data

Tags: php, android, curl, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to set data to send Firebase

```
    function sendFCM($body,$id,$title,$url) {
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $fields = array (
            'to' => $id,
            'notification' => array (
                    "body" => $body,
                    "title" => $title,
                    "icon" => $url,
AND HERE???? HOW SET DATA?
            'data' => array (
            "id_notification" => $id_notification
    )
    )
    );
    $fields = json_encode ( $fields );
    $headers = array (
            'Authorization: key=' . "",
            'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init ();
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );

    $result = curl_exec ( $ch );
    curl_close ( $ch );
    }
```

I update the code :::::::

Firebasemessaging

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        UrI alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        if(alarmSound == null){
            alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        }

        String Body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        String Titolo = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String Icona = remoteMessage.getNotification().getIcon();
        String TAG = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTag();
        String Colore = remoteMessage.getNotification().getColor();

        sendNotification(Body,Titolo,Icona,TAG,Colore);
    }
```

And in Android in `MessageReceiver()` how to get the data? For example I want to get `id_notification`.

Thanks everyone for help!

Comment: what do you mean by `id_notification`

Comment: identificator of notification

Comment: The one that you didn't send yet or the one from `NotificationManager.notify`(which also wasn't called)... well, maybe time travelling will be accessible in the future ...

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) in order to get the "id_notification" value from the RemoteMessage, you just have to read it from the Map.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // ...

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        String idNotification = remoteMessage.getData().get("id_notification");
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you update the question to add exactly the php code you are using to send the message and the AndroidManifest and the FirebaseMessagingService you extended in your Android app?